# Function-pointer syntax ambiguity

Tags: c++

Take the following example. I create a function pointer named `s`, set it to `f` and call it. This compiles fine of course:

```
void f() {}

int main() {

    void (*s)();

    s = f;

    s();

}
```

But take this next example, where I declare `s` now as a "function reference" (if it's so called) and set to `f` inline. This compiles fine as well:

```
void f() {}

int main() {

    void (&s)() = f;

    s();

}
```

What are the differences between these two ways to create and initialize a function-pointer? Note that when I use the reference syntax I am required to initialize it "in-line" to `f` whereas with the "pointer" syntax I had the ability to do it both ways. Can you explain that as well? And with that, can you explain what their differences are in terms of usability, and when must I use one form over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally the calling side has no distinct difference. But the **decl** side definitely does. As you have pointed out, references must be initialized to reference *something*. This makes them "safer", but even then there is no guarantee of "safety".

The function pointer need NOT point to a function at all. It could be NULL, or even uninitialized (pointing to garbage). Not that it matters, because you can always change it later (something you can NOT do with references).

```
void (*s)();  // uninitialized
```

or

```
void (*s)() = NULL; // set to null
```

and later

```
void foo() 
{
}

s = foo;
```

You can do none of those with a reference. The reference *must* be initialized to *something* and preferabley something *valid*:

```
void (&f)() = foo;   // ok. also references foo().
void (&f)() = *s;    // also ok, but wait, is s valid?? does it have to be??
```

However, even here a function reference is not guaranteed to be safe, just *safer*. You can certainly do this:

```
void (*s)();
void (&f)() = *s;
```

You may get a compiler warning out of this (I do, "s used before being initialized") but in the end `f` still is now a reference to a "function" that **isn't** a function at all; just the random stack garbage in the `s` pointer. Worse, since references cannot be reassigned. this thing will *always* point at garbage.

Answer (score 2):

The differences are the same as for any pointer/reference.

References must be initialized and cannot be reassigned later:

```
int i,j;
int &r = i;
r = j; // i = j, not &r == &j
```

References cannot be treated as objects distinct from the object they reference (as opposed to pointers, which are objects distinct from the object they point at)...

```
int i;
int *p = &i; // &p != &i
int &r = i;  // &r == &i
```

Using a function pointer looks syntactically the same as using a reference, but that's because of a special rule with function pointers that allows you to use them without dereferencing them.

Answer (score 2):

You said it yourself, a difference is that with a reference, you have to bind it upon declaration, which guarantees that references always refer to valid objects.
Another difference is that references cannot be rebinded after they are declared, so they refer to one and only one object throughout their lives.

Other than that they are the same thing.
I have met some purists that prefer references and said that pointers are a vestige of C that shouldn't be used.
Other people prefer pointers because they are more "explicit" about the fact that they are pointers.

Whether using one or the other depends on your needs. The way to choose is, use a reference if possible, but if you really need to be able to point it to a different function, then use a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

A reference to a type P is a lot like a const pointer to a type P (not a pointer to a const P, which is different).

As it happens most of the ways they differ are not important if your type P is a function type.  & behaves slightly differently, you can directly assign the pointer to a non const pointer, and functions that take one may not take the other.

If the type P was not a function type there would be loads of other differences -- operator=, lifetime of temporaries, etc.

In short, the answer is 'not much'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Function identifiers are expressions of function type, but they implicitly convert to pointer-to-function type or reference-to-function type. So they can be passed to constructor of either reference or pointer and to operator= of pointer.
2. Since references syntactically behave like instances, there is no way to act on the reference rather than the referred object. That's why they can only be initialized. By the way prefered syntax in C++ is with parenthesis, not `=`.
3. You should use reference when possible and pointers only if you can't use reference. The reason is that since many things can't be done to reference (pointing to NULL, changing referred object, deleting it etc.) there is fewer things you have to look for when reading the code. Plus it saves some `*` and `&` characters.